# Python data structure to implement photon simulation

Tags: python, data-structures, simulation, montecarlo, kdtree

**The Problem**

I have a function, with 2 independent variables, using which I need to construct a 2-D grid, with parameters of my choice. These parameters will be the ranges of the two independent variables, smallest/largest cell size etc.

Visually this can be thought of as a space partition data structure whose geometry is provided by my function. To each cell, I will be then assigning some properties (that will also be determined by the function and other things).

**My Idea**

Once such data structure is prepared, I can simulate a photon (in a Monte-Carlo based approach) which will travel to a cell randomly (with some constraints, which are given by the function and cell properties), will be absorbed or scattered (re-emitted) from that cell with some probabilities (at which point I will be solving the radiative transfer equation in that cell). After this, the photon, if re-emitted, with its wavelength now different, moves to a *neighbouring* cell, and will keep moving till it escapes the grid (whose boundaries were decided by the parameters) or is completely absorbed in one of the cells. So, my data structure should also be in such a way that it can access the nearest neighboring cells efficiently from a computation point of view.

**What I have done**

I looked into `scipy.spatial.kdtree` but I am not sure I will be able to assign properties to cells the way I want (though if someone can explain that, it would be really helpful as it is very good with accessing nearest neighbours). I have also looked at othe tree-based algorithms but I am a bit lost at how to implement them. Numpy arrays are, at the end of the day, matrices, which does not suit my function (it leads to wastage of memory).

So any suggestions on data structures I can use (and some nudge towards how I can) will be really nice.

Comment: As currently written, your question is both extremely broad and extremely hand-wavy. What, specifically, are your data structures supposed to store, and how, specifically, will that info be used to control the logic? It’s mighty hard to know what data structures are appropriate without any details about the logic of your program. You haven’t even specified whether you plan to use time-stepped logic or event scheduling logic, which would yield completely different implementations.

Comment: I also see a variety of design issues with your proposed grid. Are cells rectangular, hexagonal, or something else? We tend to think of light as traveling linearly, but a rectangular grid would introduce significant distortions in a time-stepped model.

Comment: Have you considered making the cells objects, whose attributes define the absorption/propagation/distortion of photons?

Comment: that's called monte-carlo light transport simulation, and there are A LOT of implementations available online, if you want my suggestion either use c++ or find an already implemented simulator for it, there are some that even JIT the simulation in c++, and no matter what you do in python you will never get anywhere near those speeds, and there is way too much information in literature.

Comment: @pjs I am really sorry and I am completely aware of the vagueness of my description of the problem. I will try to answer you questions nonetheless
1. Data structure is going to store a lot of things. For now it's temperature, but later chemical abundances as well. I think I will have to make multiple copies with same structure.

Comment: @pjs 2. The function is provides the density of the cell which then is related to optical depth. Photon (mean free) path will be dictated by all these parameters. The cell properties I mentioned is actually just the composition of the cell, which have certain albedo and other optical properties.

Comment: @pjs 3. About the grid design. The morphology can be thought of as a right triangle. Think (r,z) co-ordinates, starting from origin. I will maybe attach an image in few hours. As far as I am aware, cells are not a fixed shape. In fact, all I have is the density function in (r,z). Every coordinate represents a cell.

Comment: @pjs 4. On cells as objects. I don't have any problem with this, but there might be a lot of cells. Also how can I implement connections (as in photon random walk) between these objects? This is definitely a very good suggestion though.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Yes, I am aware of it. In fact, I actually am adapting this Python implementation from a Fortran code I already have. But my Fortran is really not good and the code is quite lengthy. I am aware of the slowness of Python, but it's more accessible and the aim for this particular Python implementation is to make it easier to use.

Comment: @peakcipher All of the info in your comments should be in the question itself. Comments are transient here on stackoverflow, questions and answers are supposed to be self-contained — they should not be based on comments.

Comment: @peakcipher Connections between objects should be easy to implement. One of the object’s instance variables could be a list of “neighbor” objects, i.e., other cells that a photon could transit to.